# How to create foreign keys in two different tables for each other in Prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I am trying to create two relatioships:

1. User -> Country(so user can have a country_id)
2. Country -> User (Country can have a foreign key created_by, but is it optional)

However I am trying to integrate these two but I get an error that  Field "country" is already defined on model "user"

```
model User {
  id                              String                            @id @default(uuid())
  name                            String                            @db.VarChar(255)
  surname                         String                            @db.VarChar(255)
  email                           String                            @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(255)
  password                        String                            @db.VarChar(255)
  phone                           String                            @db.VarChar(255)
  country_id                      String
  Country                         Country                           @relation(fields: [country_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  Country                         Country[] // Field "Country" is already defined on model "User".
}



model Country {
  id         String    @id @default(uuid())
  name       String    @unique(map: "name") @db.VarChar(255)
  created_by String?
  Users      User?     @relation(fields: [created_by], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  updatedAt  DateTime  @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  City       City[]
  Vehicle    Vehicle[]
  User       User[]
}
```

Comment: The relation fields do not exist on database, so field named Country will not exist in database. Can't you just rename the Country field? Do you mind elaborating your use case so that I can provide some actionable feedback?

Comment: I want that every client (table user but in role of a client) to assign his/her country when he registers in the system.
Also admin that are also in table user, I want where an admin creates a country, I want to store in the database the ID of the user that specific country is created.
Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Rename one of the `Country` fields in the `User` model so that all field names are unique, and then [disambiguate the relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations) by naming each relation and including the name in the `@relation` tag.

##### Explanation

Seems like there's a bit of a misunderstanding of the prisma schema, which is understandable, considering [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#relation-fields) is the primary example they give in the docs:

```
model Comment {
  id     Int
  // Other fields
  Post   Post? @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id]) // A comment can have one post
  postId Int?
}
```

From this example, it may seem like you must name your field after the other field in the foreign relation, but **this is not the case.** It could just as easily be called `post` or `commented_post` or `postWithComment`.

When [defining a model](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-fields), the schema takes the following form:

```
model [model name] {
  [field name] [field type] [optional modifiers ...]
  ...
}
```

Whether or not you are planning on using these fields, the names have to be unique. (In your case, you *have* to define two relation fields on each model to establish the desired foreign key relationships, even though you might not need to access them through the model.) **The solution is to rename your relation fields to be unique, ideally to something more suggestive of their purpose.** Here's how I might do it:

```
model User {
  id                   String       @id @default(uuid())
  ...
  country_id           String
  country              Country      @relation(fields: [country_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  countries_created    Country[]
}

model Country {
  id                   String       @id @default(uuid())
  ...
  created_by           String?
  creator              User?        @relation(fields: [created_by], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  ...
  users                User[]
}
```

Now, for our `User` model:

- `country` is the user's country of origin
- `created_countries` is the list of countries the user has created

and for our `Country` model:

- `users` is the list of users from that country
- `creator` is the user that created that country

However, we now have a problem. We have two relation fields between the `User` and `Country` models, and prisma doesn't know which relation field on `User` corresponds to which relation field on `Country`, so we have to [disambiguate these relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations). We can do so by assigning a name to each relation, and declaring the name in the `@relation` tag on **both** ends of the relation:

```
model User {
  id                   String       @id @default(uuid())
  ...
  country_id           String
  country              Country      @relation("OriginCountry", fields: [country_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  countries_created    Country[]    @relation("CreatedCountries")
}

model Country {
  id                   String       @id @default(uuid())
  ...
  created_by           String?
  creator              User?        @relation("CreatedCountries", fields: [created_by], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  ...
  users                User[]       @relation("OriginCountry")
}
```